# Symfony 6.1 Unable to login on new site using User database from 3.4 site

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I've setup a new 6.1 site from scratch and am trying to implement Security. I have a user database from a previous site in Symfony 3.4 that I am trying use, with existing password hashes and Salts - I wish to keep using the same hashes, hence the sha1 algorithm (will look at upgrading hashing algorithm later). Trying to login always returns the following:

```
  #message: "The presented password is invalid."
  #code: 0
  #file: "/** redacted **/vendor/symfony/security-http/EventListener/CheckCredentialsListener.php"
  #line: 69
  #serialized: null
  -token: null
  trace: {▼
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/security-http/EventListener/CheckCredentialsListener.php:69 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php:175 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php:326 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Session.php:258 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Session.php:278 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Session.php:70 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/security-http/Authentication/AuthenticationUtils.php:40 {▶}
    /** redacted **/src/Controller/SecurityController.php:33 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:153 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:75 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:202 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/HttpKernelRunner.php:35 {▶}
    /** redacted **/vendor/autoload_runtime.php:29 {▶}
    /** redacted **/public/index.php:5 {▶}
  }
}
```

That seems pretty straightforward that it doesn't recognise the password. However, the password is identical as that in the database being used by the Symfony 3.4 version of the site, with the exact same password hasher being used.

This is basically an out-of-the-box site, I have not done any configuration beyond trying to get Security working, I have followed the documentation exactly.

Here is my security.yaml:

```
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\Users:
            algorithm:   sha1
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Users
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                enable_csrf: false
            login_throttling:
                max_attempts: 3 # per minute
                interval: '15 minutes'
```

Here is SecurityController.php (containing route /login):

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Office;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(private ManagerRegistry $doctrine, private LoggerInterface $logger) {}

    #[Route('/login', name: 'login')]
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        $sessionStorage = new NativeSessionStorage([], new NativeFileSessionHandler());
        $session = new Session($sessionStorage);

        $doctrine    =  $this->doctrine;
        $logger  =  $this->logger;
        $logger->info('loginAction');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render(
            'security/login.html.twig',
            [
                'controller_name' => 'SecurityController',
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Here is my login.html.twig:

```
{% block PageHeader %}{% endblock %}

{% block PageContent %}
    <div style="min-height: 250px;">
        <h1>{{ 'security.login.title'|trans({}) }}</h1>
        <br />

        {% if error %}
            {{ dump(error) }}
            {% if error.messageKey is defined %}
                <div class="error">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData) }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post" class="login">
            <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}) }}</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />

            <br /><br />
            <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}) }}</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />
            
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
            <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}) }}" />
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block PageFooter %}{% endblock %}
```

Here is my Users class:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Users", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_D5428AED73FD6E34", columns={"Office"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsersRepository")
 */
class Users implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="UserId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userid;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Firstname", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Surname", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Email", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="JobTitle", type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $jobtitle;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Password", type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Salt", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Status", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CreatedOn", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdon;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CreatedBy", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdby;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="LastUpdatedOn", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastupdatedon;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="LastUpdatedBy", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastupdatedby;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted;

    /**
     * @var \Office
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Office")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Office", referencedColumnName="OfficeId")
     * })
     */
    private $office;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Usergroup", inversedBy="userid")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="usergroupmap",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UserId", referencedColumnName="UserId")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UserGroup", referencedColumnName="UserGroupId")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $usergroup = array();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->usergroup = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getUserid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->userid;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(?string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(?string $surname): self
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJobtitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->jobtitle;
    }

    public function setJobtitle(?string $jobtitle): self
    {
        $this->jobtitle = $jobtitle;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(?string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function setSalt(?string $salt): self
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?int
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(?int $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedon(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdon;
    }

    public function setCreatedon(?\DateTimeInterface $createdon): self
    {
        $this->createdon = $createdon;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedby(): ?int
    {
        return $this->createdby;
    }

    public function setCreatedby(?int $createdby): self
    {
        $this->createdby = $createdby;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastupdatedon(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->lastupdatedon;
    }

    public function setLastupdatedon(?\DateTimeInterface $lastupdatedon): self
    {
        $this->lastupdatedon = $lastupdatedon;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastupdatedby(): ?int
    {
        return $this->lastupdatedby;
    }

    public function setLastupdatedby(?int $lastupdatedby): self
    {
        $this->lastupdatedby = $lastupdatedby;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeleted(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    public function setDeleted(?\DateTimeInterface $deleted): self
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOffice(): ?Office
    {
        return $this->office;
    }

    public function setOffice(?Office $office): self
    {
        $this->office = $office;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Usergroup>
     */
    public function getUsergroup(): Collection
    {
        return $this->usergroup;
    }

    public function addUsergroup(Usergroup $usergroup): self
    {
        if (!$this->usergroup->contains($usergroup)) {
            $this->usergroup->add($usergroup);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUsergroup(Usergroup $usergroup): self
    {
        $this->usergroup->removeElement($usergroup);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): array
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        foreach ($this->usergroup as $key => $value)
        {
            $roles[] = $value->getUsergroup();
        }
        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas about how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi Cerad, that link you gave refers to "my make:auth generated authenticator class", however I don't have one of those, I'm just trying to use the out of the box Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator - are you suggesting that I make that change inside the FormLoginAuthenticator class itself?

Comment: I tried modifying Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator directly anyway, it didn't work. That did give me some more information that the "Authenticator does not support the request" message is coming from the initial GET of the login page (when there have not been any credentials POSTed to the server), so I guess this is normal and my problem is another one.

Comment: Yep.  I'm going to delete my original comment.  I would suggest making a simple check password command and verify that your sha1 stuff is even working.  I know the very latest password_hash completely ignores the salt.  I'm speculating here but you might need to use a LegacyPasswordHasherInterface just to get your salts to be used.

Comment: At the very least your User needs to implement LegacyPasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface in order to even try to use the salt.  If you can provide an actual hash/salt for one of your passwords then I might try to see if I can configure things to use it.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion re LegacyPasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface while investigating on my own! However it was still failing because of the line ```if (\strlen($hashedPassword) !== $this->hashLength || str_contains($hashedPassword, '$')) {``` in the verify function, this was always returning false because hashLength was -1. hashLength is determined in the constructor. Commenting out that check in verify() seems to have worked, not sure yet because getting another error but the new error seems to imply that password verification was done successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! First thing was to make my User class inherit from `LegacyPasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface` instead of `PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface`.

Second thing was to look in `/vendor/symfony/password-hasher/Hasher/MessageDigestPasswordHasher.php`, and in the `verify` function, comment out the block that starts with the line `if (\strlen($hashedPassword) !== $this->hashLength || str_contains($hashedPassword, '$')) {`.

This block was permanently returning false since `$this->hashLength` was always -1. `$this->hashLength` is set in the constructor, I don't know why it was always returning -1 or whether or not that check is valid, however commenting it out got me being able to login :)